# Runtime error while executing simple hashing program

Tags: c++, hash, runtime, chaining

I am creating a simple hashing program with chaining, the compiler didn't give me any error, but the program itself is crashing at the time of execution. The program logs the time difference taken by search function to a file(The dataset is x% of 1000 randomly generated numbers hashed)(I don't know if it something with the logic itself, or some technical error. I am using pocketcpp as, err..ide). Code :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

/*Code by RN:121503 * Date: 04-11-2014*/

using namespace std;

typedef struct storagelist
{
    int value;
    storagelist *next;
};

storagelist *startArray[100];

int simplehash(int n)
{
    int index;
    index=n%1000;
    return index;
}

int simplesearch(int n)
{
    int index;
    int i=0;
    storagelist *tempPointer=startArray[n]->next;
    index=simplehash(n);
    //Base address of array, i.e. array index will be null.
    if(startArray[n]->next==NULL)
    {
        //cout<<"No such key/value exist \n";
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if(tempPointer->value==n)
            {
                //cout<<"Key found \n";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                tempPointer=tempPointer->next;
            }
        }while(tempPointer->next!=NULL);
    }
}

void simpleinsert(int n)
{
    int tempIndex;
    storagelist *tempPointer;
    storagelist *tempPointertwo;
    tempIndex=simplehash(n);
    if(startArray[tempIndex]->next==NULL)
    {
        tempPointer=new storagelist;
        tempPointer->value=n;
        startArray[tempIndex]->next=tempPointer;
        tempPointer->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(tempPointer->next!=NULL)
        {
            tempPointer=tempPointer->next;
        }
        tempPointertwo=new storagelist;
        tempPointertwo->value=n;
        tempPointer->next=tempPointertwo;
        tempPointertwo->next=NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int tempRandom;
    int loopHelp;
    int randomBackup[100];
    //File handeling
    ofstream myfile;
    //Clock elements
    clock_t start, end;
    //Populating starting indices with NULL
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        startArray[i]->next=NULL;
    }
    /*generating 1000 random numbers between 1 to 10000
    and storing+hashing them*/
    srand (time(NULL));
    for (int k=0;k<100;k++)
    {
        tempRandom=rand()%10000+1;
        randomBackup[k]=tempRandom;
        simpleinsert(tempRandom);
    }
    //following are search cases with time logging
    for(int m=1;m<10;m++)
    {
        switch(m)
        {
        case 1:
            myfile.open ("10per.txt");
            for(loopHelp=0;loopHelp<(100*(10/100));loopHelp++)
            {
                start = clock();
                simplesearch(randomBackup[loopHelp]);
                end = clock();
                myfile<<loopHelp<<"\t"<<(double)(end-start)<<"\n";
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            myfile.open ("20per.txt");
            for(loopHelp=0;loopHelp<(100*(20/100));loopHelp++)
            {
                start = clock();
                simplesearch(randomBackup[loopHelp]);
                end = clock();
                myfile<<loopHelp<<"\t"<<(double)(end-start)<<"\n";
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            myfile.open ("30per.txt");
            for(loopHelp=0;loopHelp<(100*(30/100));loopHelp++)
            {   
                start = clock();
                simplesearch(randomBackup[loopHelp]);
                end = clock();
                myfile<<loopHelp<<"\t"<<(double)(end-start)<<"\n";
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            myfile.open ("40per.txt");
            for(loopHelp=0;loopHelp<(100*(40/100));loopHelp++)
            {
                start = clock();
                simplesearch(randomBackup[loopHelp]);
                end = clock();
                myfile<<loopHelp<<"\t"<<(double)(end-start)<<"\n";
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            myfile.open ("50per.txt");
            for(loopHelp=0;loopHelp<(100*(50/100));loopHelp++)
            {
                start = clock();
                simplesearch(randomBackup[loopHelp]);
                end = clock();
                myfile<<loopHelp<<"\t"<<(double)(end-start)<<"\n";
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            myfile.open ("60per.txt");
            for(loopHelp=0;loopHelp<(100*(60/100));loopHelp++)
            {
                start = clock();
                simplesearch(randomBackup[loopHelp]);
                end = clock();
                myfile<<loopHelp<<"\t"<<(double)(end-start)<<"\n";
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is visual studio enable the the debugger exception to break on access violation and when it stops walk up the callstack to your code.

Comment: Corrected that, and as for ide, I am actually using notepad++ with gcc and minigw

Comment: You should start by investigating the code where you allocate what the pointers in `startArray` are pointing to.

Comment: Corrected a slight mistake during insertion, whereby I didn't assign any starting address for temporary pointer, also corrected the search function whereby index assignment was wrong. Still, runtime errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
storagelist *startArray[1000];
[...]
int main()
{
[...]
    for(inti=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        startArray[i]->next=NULL;
```

The runtime error results from the uninitialized startArray[i], which contains only NULL-Pointers. I guess the NULL-Pointer has no member 'next' you can access at runtime, which results in a Segmentation fault.

So what you miss is creating the actual items and store them in your startArray:

```
    for(inti=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        storagelist *item = new storagelist;
        item->value = 0;
        item->next = NULL;
        //startArray[i]->next=NULL;
```

Comment: That was the problem, I just mistook array of pointers as array of objects. I wonder why didn't compiler gave me any error or so. Thanks!